# Flexdashboard shiny deployment with updating data

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, flexdashboard

I deployed a flexdashboard shiny app to shinyapps.io, which worked fine. However, I want the dashboard to automatically update when the data file on google drive updates. What are my options for setting this up? I don't want to continously manually deploy a new version to shinyapps.io.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same, and I found the following :

Option #1 : you can try to connect to a data base using shinyapp.io

ref: https://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/applications.html

Option #2 : you can work with RStudio Connect

After doing some research, I would go with option 2, because :

1. you set up an environment to publish your dashboard.
2. you have the right environment to maintain, control and update the data.

The following article explains the steps to set up an environment to answer the need

source : https://medium.com/rstudio-connect-digest/basic-builds-how-to-update-data-in-a-shiny-app-on-rstudio-connect-48593902b1e2

The following article allows you to understand the difference between shinyapp.io and RStudio connect.

Initially I pusblished my dashboard in Shinyapp.io, buying a monthly licence, but now I realized RStudio Connect was a better choice.

To understand the difference, I am posting the following comparison:

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/217240558-What-is-the-difference-between-RStudio-Connect-and-shinyapps-io-